# Magento 2 - Create Account On Order Success Page Doesn't Work

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

After purchasing an item using guest checkout, there's an option to quickly create an account on the order success page. On choosing to create an account, there seems to be some sort of error - I can see a warning/alert icon and the div background turns red but there's no error message/text.

I'm not sure if this text is getting accidentally hidden by some CSS and I'm unable to find the error message strings in any of the Magento files.

Since there is no user input at this stage, and the email address has already been validated during checkout, I'm not sure what kind of error could come up at this stage.

How do I find out what the error is without the error text?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the screen which you see after clicking on the button?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

*You have to check the **exception.log & system.log** for track the issue.*

When you a user click on `Create an Account` button then

> [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Account/Create](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Account/Create.php#L89)

file hit. So you have to check  catch section of try block this file

```
 catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

check  app/design/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/registration.html

Change

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
<div>
    <!-- ko if: isFormVisible -->
    <p data-bind="i18n: 'You can track your order status by creating an account.'"></p>
    <p><span data-bind="i18n: 'Email Address'"></span>: <span data-bind="text: getEmailAddress()"></span></p>
    <form method="post" data-bind="submit: createAccount">
        <input type="submit" class="action primary" data-bind="value: $t('Create an Account'), disable: creationStarted" />
    </form>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: accountCreated -->
    <p data-bind="i18n: 'A letter with further instructions will be sent to your email.'"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

TO

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
<div>
    <!-- ko if: isFormVisible -->
    <p data-bind="i18n: 'You can track your order status by creating an account.'"></p>
    <p><span data-bind="i18n: 'Email Address'"></span>: <span data-bind="text: getEmailAddress()"></span></p>
    <a class="action primary" data-bind="attr: { href: getUrl() }">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Create an Account'" />
    </a>
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

because delegateCreate account only accept `get` method not `post` method